# How to logout in react

Tags: reactjs, logout, jsx

I'm trying to logout using this method:
In render I have a div like this:

```
<div>
   <a href="#" onClick={this.logout()}>LOGOUT</a>
</div>
```

and the logout function:

```
logout() {
    // localStorage.clear();
    location.href = 'localhost:3000';
}
```

At localhost:3000 I have the login page.

Put when I press logout, nothing happends. What can I do?
Thank you

Comment: where is the logout function being called?

Comment: I don't see a button to press ?

Comment: this question doesn't make any sense. what are you trying to 'logout' of?

Comment: if you're just trying to navigate, make sure you add http:// to localhost:3000

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I have copyed the wrong code! Now you can see where I'm calling logout function. And I have changed the url, by adding http:// but still not working, and the first time when I pressed the button, I saw in the console the message wrote in console log in the logout function. The second time, when I pressed the button it just clears what I have in console log.

Answer (score 23):

this solved my problem

```
 logout() {
        localStorage.clear();
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Give to us the Minimal Example to be tested.

You already checked if your function is being called? Try to put some `console.log` inside `logout()`, it smells [Binding to methods of React class](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html) issue.

Try to insert http:// inside location.href, like this: `location.href = 'http://localhost:3000';`

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I have copyed the wrong code! Now you can see where I'm calling logout function. And I have changed the url, by adding http:// but still not working, and the first time when I pressed the button, I saw in the console the message wrote in console log in the logout function. The second time, when I pressed the button it just clears what I have in console log.

Comment: It seems like it renders it without pressing the logout. Because when I try to login, it redirects me to the login page.